# text-shadow applying to all the text on website?

Tags: html, css

So i have this weird problem if it's even a problem(?) might just be me who doesn't understand CSS and how it works

i created a css class called textShadow

```
.textshadow {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000000;
}
```

and when i added it to en element suddenly all the text had the same text-shadow is it supposed to be like this?

if you add text-shadow with

```
style="text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000000;"
```

only the specefide element gets text-shadow

Thank you for reading my post and happy holidays!

EDIT: Adding some html code

```
  <div class="w-container">
        <div class="w-slider w-hidden-tiny headerslider" data-animation="slide" data-duration="500" data-infinite="1" data-delay="4000" data-autoplay="1">
            <div class="w-slider-mask">
                <div class="w-slide headerSliderContentPadding" style="text-align: center">
                    <h1 class="textOnDark1 textshadow">Suspendisse varius enim in eros elementum tristique!
                    </h1>
                    <h4 class="w-hidden-tiny w-hidden-small textOnDark1 textshadow">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse varius enim in eros elementum tristique. Duis cursus, mi quis viverra ornare, eros dolor interdum nulla, ut commodo diam libero vitae erat. Aenean faucibus nibh et justo cursus id rutrum lorem imperdiet. Nunc ut sem vitae risus tristique posuere.
                    </h4>
                    <div class="w-hidden-main w-hidden-medium" style="display: inline-block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                        <a class="buttonBlue btn extraPaddíng10px" href="#">Button Text</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="w-slide">
                </div>
                <div class="w-slide">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="w-slider-arrow-left">
                <div class="w-icon-slider-left"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="w-slider-arrow-right">
                <div class="w-icon-slider-right"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="w-slider-nav w-round w-num"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I only want the elements that have the textshadow class to have text-shadow, but all the element get's text-shadow when i run it in chrome, firefox and internet explorer (even the div slider get's shadowing) why is that?

Comment: Show some example HTML.

Comment: Do you mean all the text to the website has that text shadow, or all the text to the element in which you placed the class/style had the shadow?

Comment: Welcome to SO. So you should check out how to ask a good question: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask you should at least show us some relevant code or **even better:** put it into a js fiddle to make it easier for us to troubleshoot

Comment: Your problem is not a *problem* problem. Your code is doing exactly what it is suppose to do. Readup this small tutorial: http://www.tizag.com/cssT/inline.php

Comment: you should post question only when you get error

Comment: you can think of cascading styles as cascading down into their inner elements. so, if you apply certain automatically inherited styles i.e font-size, etc, the child elements will also reflect these.

Comment: @sanojlawrence That is not true. It's ok to ask why something doesn't work as intended, even if there's no syntax error.

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/95hum2vo/ It's likely that you have the class applied to some parent tag not shown here.

Comment: can you please put this in a jsfiddle so we can see the code in full context?

Comment: @Todd ill try to do that :)

Comment: @GraceLee all the text have textshadow even if I change page the text-shadow persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some html inspection i found that the class had for some reason been applied to the `<html>` tag(?)

and some other weird classes as well i guess it have to do something with how webflow works (forgot to mention that the website was created with webflow) why it dose this i have no idé but at least i know why now :)

Thanks for all the suggestions and help guys you are great